# Не могу подключиться к Postgres Docker?

Tags: postgresql, golang, docker

Создаю Postgres в Docker

> docker run -it --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_DB=db postgres

Код подключения написан на Golang

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {

    connStr := "user=user password=pass dbname=db sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    _, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE if not exists Products (id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, model varchar(30) NOT NULL, company varchar(30) NOT NULL, price integer NOT NULL);")
    result, err := db.Exec("insert into Products (model, company, price) values ('iPhone X', $1, $2)", "Apple", 72000)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result.RowsAffected())
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> panic: pq: password authentication failed for user "user"

Ошибка понятна, но не знаю в чём может быть проблема и как её исправить.

Comment: я не вижу, где вы задаете к какому хосту и порту делаете соединение. При той команде запуска postgres в докере, postgres не будет слушать на порту по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не проброшен порт, необходимо заменить запуск контейнера
   при условии что у вас порт постреса в контейнере 5432

   docker run -it --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_DB=db postgres -p 5432:5432
2. Сокет в connStr тоже стоит указывать, с учетом что мы выше пробросили порт на 5432 на локалхост, dsn будет выглядеть примерно так

   connStr := "host=0.0.0.0 port=5432 user=user password=pass dbname=db sslmode=disable"